# Arbol Binario de Busqueda C++ que acepte tanto letras como Numeros?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Mi árbol esta construido, el problema es que al utilizar `char` solo me acepta el primer dígito que ingrese (No hay problema si solo quisiera ingresar Letras) pero también me gustaría que aceptara números y nombres.

¿Tienen alguna idea de como podría lograr esto?

Si lo cambio a `string` tampoco funciona, el árbol se imprime/ordena así cuando ingreso esta lista de números: `100,0,50,35`.

```
             100
           /      \
          0        50
                  /
                35
```

O sea, claramente no los ordena bien, supongo que estará tomando en cuenta solo el primer dígito.

```
struct Nodo{
    string dato;
    Nodo *izq;
    Nodo *der;
    Nodo *padre;
};
Nodo *arbol=NULL;

Nodo *crearNodo(char,Nodo *);
void Insertar(Nodo *&, char, Nodo *);
void Eliminar(Nodo*, char);
[..etc]
```

Comment: ¿ Tines pensado ya como ordenarlo si usas cadenas y números mezclados ? ¿ `"hola"` va **antes** o **después** del número `100` ?

Comment: No toma en cuenta solo el primer dígito, pero para una computadora no es lo mismo una cadena con el valor `'100'`, que el número `100`.

Comment: La comparación de cadenas funciona comparando caracter por caracter hasta encontrar una diferencia (comparándolos como caracteres, según su código `ASCII` (o unicode), no como números).  Así, la cadena `10045` es menor que la cadena `3` o que `37`, pero la cadena `14` es mayor que la cadena `100` (donde claramente el primer dígito es igual).  Una solución práctica para esto, podría ser ingresar los números con una longitud fija (que podría o no tener ceros a la izquierda, aprovechando que `' '` es menor que `'0'`, de manera que `'    9'` sea menor que `'   10'`

Comment: Otra es almacenar una cadena y un número en cada nodo, y especializar las comparaciones al insertar y eliminar nodos, para tomar en cuenta y hacer lo que sea que tu quieras hacer cuando se compara un número con una cadena.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, un inciso: Un nodo no es un árbol, de la misma manera que un diente no es un animal.

En tu programa falta una clase que gestione los nodos. Los nodos son una parte interna de la estructura del árbol y, como tales, no debería estar expuestos alegremente al resto del programa.

Considera implementar una clase que gestione el árbol:

```
class Arbol
{
public:
  void Insertar(char valor);
  void Eliminar(char valor);
  // ...

private:
  Nodo* root;
};
```

> O sea, claramento no los ordena bien

Los está ordenando correctamente. Lo que sucede es que los está tratando como si fuesen cadenas de caracteres, es decir:

```
100 ->                        primer nodo
0   -> '0' < '1',             nodo a la izquierda de  100
50  -> '5' > '1',             nodo a la derecha de 100
35  -> '3' > '1' y '3' < '5', nodo a la izquierda de 50
```

> pero tambien me gustaria que aceptara Numeros y Nombres. Tienen alguna idea de como podria lograr esto?

Te refieres a poder mezclar todo eso en un mismo árbol? Entonces lo primero que tienes que determinar es un mecanismo que permita comparar todos esos elementos entre sí:

- Cómo comparas una cadena de caracters y un número?
- Cómo comparas un caracter y un número?
- Cómo comparas un caracter con una cadena?

Como estos mecanismos no han sido determinados en la pregunta, esta rama del desarrollo se para aquí.

Si, en cambio, lo que te gustaría es usar `Nodo` para crear árboles de distinto tipo (un árbol de números, otro de cadenas texto, otro de caracteres sueltos, ...), entonces podrías optar por usar plantillas.

Podemos empezar por definir los comparadores:

```
// Comparador por defecto
template<class T>
struct LessThanComparator
{
  bool Compare(T const& a, T const& b) const
  { return a < b; }
};
```

Tanto los tipos nativos, `int`, `char`, ..., como la clase `std::string` disponen de una sobrecarga adecuada del operador `<`, por lo que el trabajo del comparador podría terminar aquí. Únicamente si necesitamos un comparador especial, por ejemplo si necesitamos comparar *strings* sin tener en cuenta el uso de mayúsculas, entonces podríamos crear un comparador especial:

```
struct CaseInsensitiveComparator
{
  bool Compare(std::string const& a, std::string const& b)
  {
    size_t size = a.size() < b.size() ? a.size() : b.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
      char charA = tolower(a[i]);
      char charB = tolower(b[i]);
      if (charA < charB)
        return true;
      else if( charA > charB )
        return false;
    }

    return a.size() < b.size();
};
```

Y con esto ya tendríamos todos los mimbres necesarios para crear nuestra clase `Nodo`:

```
template<class T, class Comparator = LessThanComparator<T>>
struct Nodo
{
  T dato;
  Nodo *padre;
  Nodo *izq;
  Nodo *der;

  explicit Nodo(T const& value, Nodo* parent = nullptr)
    : dato{value}
    , padre{parent}
    , izq{nullptr}
    , der{nullptr}
  { }

  bool operator<(Nodo const& other) const
  {
    Comparator c;
    return c.Compare(dato, other.dato);
  }
};
```

De esta forma, insertar un nuevo nodo en el árbol es ahora más sencillo:

```
template<class T>
void Insertar(T const& valor)
{
  Nodo * nodo = /* raiz del arbol */;
  Nodo * nuevo = new Nodo(valor);

  while( true )
  {
    if( nodo->Compare(nuevo) )
    {
      if( nodo->der = nullptr )
      {
        nodo->der = nuevo;
        nuevo->padre = nodo;
        return;
      }
      else
      {
        nodo = nodo->der;
      }
    }
    else if( nuevo->Compare(nodo) )
    {
      if( nodo->izq == nullptr )
      {
        nodo->izq = nuevo;
        nuevo->padre = nodo;
        return;
      }
      else
      {
        nodo = nodo->izq;
      }
    }
    else // Ambos nodos tienen el mismo valor
    {
      delete nuevo;
      return;
    }
  }
}
```